# Strange runtime error declaring instance of class Java

Tags: java, class, instance

I'm making a game in java and consistenetly get the strangest bug. I have a class called weapon. Then I create an instance of it called primary. After I create an instance and call it secondary. for some strange reason, primary gets overwritten with secondary's values. My instructor and I both looked at it and couldn't figure it out. Here's the code:

```
public class weapon {
        static String type;
        static String name;
        static int weight;
        static int damage;
        static int dodge;
        weapon(String c, String n, int w, int da, int dod) {

                type = c;
                name = n;
                weight = w;
                damage = da;
                dodge = dod;

        }
        //getters
        String getType(){
                return type;
        }
        String getName(){
                return name;
        }
        Integer getWeight(){
                return weight;
        }
        Integer getDamage(){
                return damage;
        }
        Integer getDodge(){
                return dodge;
        }
        //setters
        void setType(String c){
                c=type;
        }
        void setName(String n){
                n=name;
        }
        void setWeight(Integer w){
                w=weight;
        }
        void setDamage(Integer da){
                damage=da;
        }
        void setDodge(Integer dod){
                dodge=dod;
        }
}

/*At the top of my main class I create both instances like this because the instances are created in if statements and I need to access them.*/
weapon primary;
weapon secondary;
//I create primary like this earlier in the code like this
primary = new weapon("primary","sword", 8, 6, -1);
//and then when I run this I get the output "sword" "Heavy Sword".
System.out.println(primary.getName());
secondary = new weapon("secondary", "huge sword", 9, 7, -2);
System.out.println(primary.getName());
```

Comment: please share the relevant code here itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your member variables are defined as static :

```
    static String type;
    static String name;
    static int weight;
    static int damage;
    static int dodge;
```

That's why the values of the second instance override the first (since static members are class veriables - there is a single copy of them across all instances of the class).

Removing the static keyword would solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

All the properties of your `Weapon` class are *static*, which means they are shared among all instances you create.

Remove *static* to make them instance variables instead, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

All the member variables are declared as `static`. When you declare a member variable as `static` all the objects of that class shares the same copy of those variables. If one object changes value on a variable, it changes for other objects as well.

Simply remove the `static` keyword.

`Weapon` appears to be a bean class, it' better to encapsulate if properly with `private` member variable and `public` getter/setters.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a class with class wide variables rather than variables that are different for each object created.

Instead use:

```
public class weapon {
        private String type;
        private String name;
        private int weight;
        private int damage;
        private int dodge;
        weapon(String c, String n, int w, int da, int dod) {
```

I would suggest you use the following pattern when you define classes to help ensure your "class fields" and "object fields" are well described

```
public class <name-of-class> {
// Class fields
    <private|public|protected> [final] static ....
// Object fields
     private ...
```